# No hay una función coincidente para la llamada a <función>, al pasar una función lambda a otra función

Tags: c++, lambda

Se supone que tengo que crear una función lambda y pasarla a la otra función. Pero no sé por qué no funciona. He intentado asignarla a una variable y pasarla directamente como parámetro pero de ninguna forma funciona. El error que me da es este:

> error: no hay una función coincidente para la llamada a ‘prefix_process(BTree::Ref&, print_prefix(std::ostream&, typename BTree::Ref) [with T = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream; typename BTree::Ref = std::shared_ptr<BTree >]::<lambda(const int&)>&)’

```
prefix_process(typename BTree<T>::Ref tree, Processor& p)
    {
        assert(tree != nullptr);
        bool retVal = true;
        if (tree->is_empty()==false)
        {
            retVal = p(tree->item());
            retVal = retVal && prefix_process<T, Processor>(tree->left(), p);
            retVal = retVal && prefix_process<T, Processor>(tree->right(), p);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    
    
    template <class T>
    std::ostream&
    print_prefix(std::ostream& out, typename BTree<T>::Ref tree)
    {
        //You must create a lambda function with a parameter to be printed and
        //  use a prefix_process to process the tree with this lambda.
        //Remenber: the lambda must return true.
        auto p=[&out](T const& value){out<<value<<" "; return true;};
        prefix_process(tree,p);
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Explicá a qué te referís con _no funciona_. Además, dale un título relevante a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el compilador dice "*no hay una función coincidente para la llamada a ‘prefix_process ...*", nos está indicando que ha intentado llamar a una función llamada `prefix_process` con unos argumentos pero que ninguna función con el nombre `prefix_process` los acepta.

¿Qué parámetros acepta `prefix_process`?:

```
prefix_process(typename BTree<T>::Ref tree, Processor& p)
```

Acepta una instancia de `BTree<T>::Ref` como primer parámetro y una referencia a `Processor` como segundo. Y ese es el problema (si lo combinas con lambdas).

---

Las lambdas por definición son inmutables, así que no puedes tener una referencia no constante a una lambda que es conceptualmente constante, [este código reproduce tu error](https://tio.run/##NYu9CsIwEIBn7ykOBEkGoXulz9BdHGK8SCC5HOl1KKXPHoPo@v14katPjt@tnSP7tL4Ib7EsWsnlCUApS3LaoW5C7DLhPMGzlITBzHgRCzucKulaGcUMdoQDILJidpHN1wZzf5iO7I6/MLi00IhHr//v0MfWPg):

```
template <typename P>
bool f(P &p)
{
    return p(0);
}

int main()
{
    f([](int){ return false; });
    return 0;
}
```

Si aceptas una referencia constante a `Processor` o usas una instancia en lugar de una referencia el error desaparece:

```
template <typename P>
bool f_const(const P &p)
{
    return p(0);
}

template <typename P>
bool f_instancia(P p)
{
    return p(0);
}

int main()
{
    f_const([](int){ return false; });     // Ok
    f_instancia([](int){ return false; }); // Ok
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY4xCsMwDEXn@BSCQnGGkuwpOUP2UorqKsVgyyZRhhJydteElC4lQxcNX@9Lz8R4Mg75mdLBsnHTg@BswygDoW@VEvLRoeRQXpEYPUHXqnsIDnrdwTGWalbFQDINDFHXZaOW/dbNBB5FrxP@u2BzFdlYzAa/65YFPFrW67aqen256hyWM2xoj26kBpbMFx@nfeb7dY/bojprpPQG)</kbd>.